# Flat Rate shipping for different customer groups?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to set a flat rate shipping method with two different prices for two different customer groups?

Googled around, but couldn't find one, and why isn't this as easy as one would imagine it be to setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create this option by copy Flatrate file `core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php` in local code pool `local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php`.

you need to modify code in `collectRates` function.

```
$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
    $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
} elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
    $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
} else {
    $shippingPrice = false;
}
```

Replace the above code using the below code:

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    //not logged in
    $flatRatePrice = $this->getConfigData('price'); 
}else{
    // logged in
    $groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
    $group = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($groupId)->getData('customer_group_code');
    $group = strtolower($group);
    switch ($group) {
        case 'general': //Set price for different customer group
            $flatRatePrice = 10;    
            break;
        case 'retailer':
            $flatRatePrice = 20;    
            break;
        case 'wholesale':
            $flatRatePrice = 30;    
            break;
        default:
            $flatRatePrice = $this->getConfigData('price'); 
    } 
}

$result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O') { // per order
    $shippingPrice = $flatRatePrice;
} elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I') { // per item
    $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $flatRatePrice) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $flatRatePrice);
} else {
    $shippingPrice = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am quite familiar with PHP code, but quite new to Magento. Is it considered good practice to change (even though we copy a copy over to local) code like this? Could there by any down sides by doing it like this?

Comment: We can copy the core file in local code pool for custom requirement modification. when we do magento upgrade, we also need to update core files as well that are in local code pool. If you don't want to do this you can override the Flatrate model by creating custom module with same changes.

Comment: Ok, this seems like a perfect opportunity for practicing my Magento dev skills. :) Thanks for the help!